# PrimeFaces 3.4.1 Spring 3.1.2 Hibernate 4.1.7

Tags: primefaces

Im developing an application with JSF2, PrimeFaces, Spring, Hibernate. In Console DOES NOT present/show any error. However, some of PrimeFaces components are not working. I think it is incompatibility with a Library, but I did not discover which one(s). Here follows my libraries:

```
aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
hibernate-c3p0-4.1.7.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar
hibernate-ehcache-4.1.7.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.7.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.faces-2.1.17.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jstl.jar
jta-1.1.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
poi-3.7.jar
postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar
primefaces-3.4.1.jar
rome-1.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-nop-1.5.2.jar
spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Thanks a lot! :)

**EDIT**

This is one of the components that is not working. It should return to me toner names and models:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="modeloToner" value="#{tonerBean.modeloToner}">
    <p:ajax update="form:impressorasCompativeis" listener="#tonerBean.findImpressorasCompativeis}" process="form:modeloToner" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="Nenhum" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{tonerBean.listModeloToner}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Generated HTML, it has the values but is not working. Other components are not working either.

```
<select id="form:modeloToner_input" name="form:modeloToner_input">
    <option value="Nenhum">Selecione...</option>
    <option value="HP 530">HP 530</option>
    <option value="HP 532" selected="selected">HP 532</option>
    <option value="HP 53X">HP 53X</option>
    <option value="Lexmark 12738826">Lexmark 12738826</option>
   <option value="Samsung 208L">Samsung 208L</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try to provide more information. What is the code you run doing? What it does should provide information of what libraries are accessed.

Comment: <p:selectOneMenu id="modeloToner" value="#{tonerBean.modeloToner}">
<p:ajax update="form:impressorasCompativeis" listener="#tonerBean.findImpressorasCompativeis}" process="form:modeloToner" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="Nenhum" />
<f:selectItems value="#{tonerBean.listModeloToner}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: That is one of the componets that is not working. It should return to me the tonners names and models. But is not working.

Comment: <select id="form:modeloToner_input" name="form:modeloToner_input"><option value="Nenhum">Selecione...</option><option value="HP 530">HP 530</option><option value="HP 532" selected="selected">HP 532</option><option value="HP 53X">HP 53X</option><option value="Lexmark 12738826">Lexmark 12738826</option><option value="Samsung 208L">Samsung 208L</option></select>                     As you can see, this is the HTML generated! It has values, however the componets is not working, it does not show the values on screen, as well there is other componets is not working, this one is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your p:selectOneMenu does not return the value because it does not have converter. Improve your question for other components and let us try to solve

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="modeloToner" value="#{tonerBean.modeloToner}" converter="converter">
    <p:ajax update="form:impressorasCompativeis" listener="#tonerBean.findImpressorasCompativeis}" process="form:modeloToner" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." itemValue="Nenhum" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{tonerBean.listModeloToner}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and the converter class

```
@FacesConverter(value="converter")
public class Converter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    YourObject o = new YourObject();
    // some operations to set the parameters of Object based on the String
    return location;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    YourObject o = (YourObject) value;
    String string;
    // some operations to save the parameters of Object into a String
    return string;
}
}
```